# Angular - Load from assets folder

Tags: angular, sass

My folder structure looks like

> ```
> src
>    styles.scss
>    sass
>       app.scss
>       composants
>           _icons.scss
>    assets
>       img
>           icons
>               alternative_medicine.svg
> ```

Inside my _icons.scss, I have the following

```
.icon-alternative_medicine {
     background: url(../../assets/img/icons/alternative_medicine.svg);
}
```

Inside my app.scss, I have the following

```
@import "composants/icons";
```

Inside my styles.scss, I have the following

```
@import  "./sass/app.scss";
```

I have the below erreur

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: xxxx\src\webapp\src\sass\composants\_icons.scss:25:20: Can't resolve '../../assets/img/icons/alternative_medicine.svg' in 'xxxx\src\webapp\src'

  24 |     .icon-alternative_medicine {
> 25 |         background: url(../../assets/img/icons/alternative_medicine.svg);
     |                    ^
  26 |     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the absolute path. Something like `/src/assets/img/icons/alternative_medicine.svg`.